# How to properly organize statements in my function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to implement a somewhat complicated function and would like to avoid recycling code when all I need is to divide it into to appropriate statements.

I have a form for adding and editing content. If the user wishes to add new content the form is empty and after he provides all the required input the input is inserted into the database (the form calls the save function and gives `new` as argument). One of the inputs is an image. The image is only required when the user is adding new content. In this scenario my function works like this:

```
function save($method)

    if $method == "new"{
     1. collect input
     2. check if image was provided: if($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] != '')
       2.1 upload original image
       2.2 create and upload thumb to thumb folder
       2.3 create and upload resized image to cover folder
       3.3 insert input into DB
     3. else reload page with error
    }
```

I am now trying to implement the edit function using the same method, only the submit button now provides ID of the content as argument for the function. It is here where I get stuck. I can't figure out which additional conditions I should be adding and where I should put them. I need the function to work as follows:

when `$method` is `"new"` and image is selected run the full step `1` & `2`

when `$method` is `"new"` and image wasn't provided run the step `1` and `2` where `2` gives error and runs `3`

when `$method` is `"X"` and image is provided run the full step `1` & `2` but instead of insert do update on content id `X`

when `$method` is `"X"` and image is not provided ignore the image upload & manipulation and update all the field except image

I hope this makes sense for you. I am not asking for the actual PHP code, all I would like to know is what should I be checking for and where. I just don't want to use the upload code three times when it always does the same, etc. Thank you for reading and in advance for your replies. I will continue working on this myself and will update the question if Ill figure it out.

Comment: one suggestion is to really clearly separate the methods based on the errors that can come from the user -- no image, file not a valid image format -- VERSUS server errors like it didn't create the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your function into several functions, some of which may take an extra parameter or two. Then call those functions from functions you write to implement your various "methods."

Comment: Yeah, I'm just considering that option. Will post an update soon.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I grouped the statements as follows:

```
if method == NEW && no image
    reload page with error
else
    if file exists
        upload image
        if upload failed
            reload page with error
        else
            create thumb
            create cover
            data array (name, ..., image paths)
        if method == NEW
            db insert, data array
        else //we are updating
            db update, where id = $method, data array
        redirect manager
    else
        data array (name, ..., NO IMG DETAILS)
        db update, where id = $method, data array
        redirect content
    }
}
```

Definitely not the best practice, but it works. I didn't really want to create additional functions and call those as the amount of additional code would be about the same. The only things I recycle now are the `data array` and `redirect content`.